# Records less in data frame

Tags: r

I have found few people posted similar issues but still can't solve my problem. The expected objects in the dataframe were 957463 but only 392400 extracted out.

I used `read.delim2("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", fill = TRUE)` to create dataframe with the expected records but the output were less than expected.

```
#set working directory --------------------------------

L <- setwd("C:/Users/abmo8004/Documents/R Project/csv/")

#List files in the path ------------------------

l <- list.files(L)

#form dataframe from csv file ---------------------------

df <- read.delim2("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", fill = TRUE)
```

I expect the output to be 957463 , but the actual output is 392400. Can anyone please look at the codes?

Comment: Really hard if not impossible to know without access to the actual `csv` file.

Comment: It might help to use `comment.char=""`, but it's not possible to tell without the data.